# cmake generated VS project can't break point

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am currently able to set up and compile a a visual studio project using cmake however I am unable to breakpoint in source at all. Originally I was warned by VS when I tried to run with the debugger that debug symbols could not be found. To fix this I simply went to the projects properties and selected Linker->Debugging and set "Generate Debug Info"  to yes. Now it generates the necessary pdb file, however if I put a break point in the source code it will hollow out and tell me that no symbols where loaded for the document.

So my question is why is it not matching the source to the pdb file and what can I do to correct this?

Thanks.

Here's a git repo with a simple example: https://github.com/Samurai336/CmakeSimple

Comment: You should not have to change any setting at all in Visual Studio for CMake generated projects to be able to set a breakpoint. After switching to CMake did you clean build your project. Although remember with CMake it is NOT recommended to have your build tree included with the source so if you followed that the tree should have been clean..

Comment: So it sounds like I am not setting a flag somewhere correctly so that when I hit generate in cmake it knows to set the project to generate pdb's. Any idea what I might be missing in my cmake?

Comment: By default cmake will set the correct values. If you somehow disabled that I would use the Delete cache option in cmake-gui and reset your generator then build your application clean. Also if you did not select an out of source build this will be a perfect time to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by out of source Build. The build directory is outside the source directory if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes. http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F

Comment: Ok. In that case I was already doing that.

Comment: If resetting does not work. Please try to create a very small example that you can post that exhibits the issue. Its very hard to debug with this limited amount of info.

Comment: Ok its back to the original issue of it not creating debug symbols (a pdb) for the exe its generating.

Comment: ya let me throw something up fast.

Comment: Ok here's a simple example where that happens. I am using the cmake gui on windows to do configuration.

https://github.com/Samurai336/CmakeSimple

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way (I've made this mistake myself) - you *are* running a Debug configuration aren't you?

Comment: I am new to Cmake so I'm here to make mistakes and learn. As far as I know I am running a debug configuration, I figured that's what I need to debug and break point.

Comment: I mean in Visual Studio.  There's a drop-down box that shows your current chosen build configuration.  If you've got "Release" selected, you won't get debugging symbols normally.

Comment: Ah, ya it says debug in that window for me. Though if it was set to release it should not have warned me about missing debug symbols right?

Comment: No - it'll let you try and run a Release build in the debugger, but will give you the warnings you probably already saw.

Comment: Double Checked configuration manager has everything pointing to debug.

Comment: You mentioned you switched on linker debugging.  Did you also switch on debugging info in "C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format"?  It should normally be set to `/Zi` or `/ZI` for Debug builds.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work :/.

Comment: What generator are you using? I get the sense that you are doing nmake from your CMakeLists.txt. I never use that. Although I am not sure that would cause the inability to debug.

Comment: I am generating a Visual Studio 11 project with the cmake gui.

Comment: I also had this problem. I used `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` in my CMake  text. However, my VS project was in x64-Debug mode. When I commented  `#set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` this line the breakpoints came back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured out what the problem was, thanks to digging deeper into user [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424459/fraser)'s comment, where he asked if I set my debug information format to "/Zi or /ZI". Well it was set to Zi so to put the science back in computer science I gave /ZI a shot. The compiler yelled at me that " '/ZI' and '/02' are incompatible." So today I looked into what the /02 flag is and realized that it was max speed optimization flag and had a hunch that was why it was having issues debugging. Sure enough when I changed the flag to '/Od'(disabled) everything break pointed accordingly.

This leaves me with a one major question though: How do I set these flags for the VS compiler from cmake?

I'll probably pose this as a separate question if I don't find it already answered.

Thanks for the help everyone.